# How to get mimetype of a texture in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Given the following piece of code

```
Texture my_image = Resources.Load<Texture>("cool_weapon");
```

Is it possible to determine the original mime-type of the image?

```
string mime_type = GetMimeType(my_image);

mime_type; // "image/png", "image/jpg", etc
```

Comment: Probably not. Unity converts textures over to an internal format.

Comment: @Draco18s Is it possible to get it from a file path? And use `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(image);` to extract the file path given some texture?

Comment: `AssetDatabase` only works in the editor. If you want file system access during runtime, that's what the `Application.persistentDataPath` is for. Just use standard file IO.

Comment: May I ask what you need it for?

Comment: @derHugo, I need the file mime type because I am making a Unity Editor Plugin to upload images to a website using a REST API.

Comment: The question is where do you get your texture from? And why don't you directly upload the according image instead? For your question: Would it be enough to check if the texture contains any transparent alpha pixel and if it does upload it as PNG if not as JPG?

Comment: If you create the Texture in the UnityEditor (which seems to be the case) than ofcourse you can use anything existing in the `UnityEditor` namespace and add those textures e.g. to a dictionary from Texture to MimeType and use e.g. [TextureImporter.DoesSourceTextureHaveAlpha](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter.DoesSourceTextureHaveAlpha.html) to determin which one to use